# Spring NamedParameterJdbcTemplate + an array of Integers + Sybase

Tags: spring, sybase

Sooo.. We found a bug and the stack pretty much looked like this

```
com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybSQLException: Class [java.lang.Integer not found. Check and make sure that the class has been installed, and an entry exists in Sysxtypes.
```

Then I thought, aaaaw, I just have to convert 'em into primitives.

```
int[] ids = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(set.toArray(new Integer[set.size()]));
```

And then plugged the ids into the query

```
return namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query("select distinct id from Coffee where id in ( :ids )", Collections.singletonMap("ids", ids),
            new ParameterizedRowMapper<Integer>(){
            public Integer mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                return rs.getInt("id");
            }
        });
```

Ok. Then I got this;

```
com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybSQLException: Class [I not found. Check and make sure that the class has been installed, and an entry exists in Sysxtypes.
```

I've never had any problems using either Integer nor int when I'm using the spring jdbc templates together with sybase. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

instead of converting to primitives you need to make it a List rather than an array

instead of this

> int[] ids =
>   ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(set.toArray(new
>   Integer[set.size()]));

you will need to do

> Arrays.asList(ids)